# JAXB - Xml Annotation in Parent class to only set a specific field in child class

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

Let's say we have a person who has a Child and I want to annotate the object reference to only map a specific field in the Child class to the parent object.
Which annotation will I be using then?

The xml looks like this:

```
<Person>
    <Child>Peter</Child>
</Person>
```

POJOs looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name = "Child")
    private Child child;
}

public class Child {
    @XmlElement(name = "Child")
    private String name;
}
```

But this doesnt work at all, I've also tried XmlElementRef etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Child {
    @XmlValue
    private String name;
}
```